# Onclick event in GWT custom button in title bar of DialogBox

Tags: gwt

I need to add button in title bar of the DialogBox that open some documentation;

My HelpButton class looks like this:

```
public class HelpButtonSmall extends Button {


    public HelpButtonSmall(final String name) {
        super();
        setHTML("<input type=\"image\" src=\"/img/ico-help-sm.png\" name=\"image\">");
        addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                Window.alert("Help");

            }
        });
    }       
}
```

On my dialog box I'm adding button in title bar like this:

```
HTML caption = ((HTML)this.getCaption());
HelpButtonSmall smallButton = new HelpButtonSmall("Show help alert");
caption.getElement().appendChild(smallButton.getElement());
```

The problem is that after clicking on button alert message doesn't show.

Please help me resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `getElement()` you are returning a native handler of DOM element and by doing that any logic done as a Widget is lost, that includs the `addClickHandler`.

If the perpose is to add a close button, there is other ways to achieve that. Here is one of [theme](http://zone817.blogspot.ca/2010/08/close-button-in-caption-bar-of-gwt.html).